# iptables rule with destination address is not working

Tags: iptables, routing, ubuntu-12.04

I've got 2 mangle rules:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -d 54.228.209.255 -j MARK --set-xmark 1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-xmark 3
```

Now I do `telnet 54.228.209.255 80` and look at my rules

```
iptables --list -t mangle -v -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 604K packets, 598M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 MARK       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            54.228.209.255       MARK set 0x1
  505  244K MARK       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 MARK set 0x3
```

Both rules were supposed to receive some packets but first rule didn't. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried to get some hints by turning on logging? See the the various `--log-` options on the manpage. The output is visible with `dmesg`.

Comment: @ott-- obviously second rule will log messages an first will not

Comment: I wonder if iptables silently skipped the first rule. Can you add this to the 2nd rule: `-d ! 54.228.209.255` and check the packet count afterwards?

Comment: @ott-- my question was already asked by ALex_hha. Now I think I'll use `iproute2` for this rules so config will be the same for local and forwarded packets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To locally generated packets you must use OUTPUT chain

```
# iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -d 54.228.209.255 -j MARK --set-xmark 1
# iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-xmark 3
```

Comment: This rules are supposed to work for both local and forwarded packets. Where to put them in this case?

Comment: No, it work only with local packets.

Comment: Thanks. Now I think I'll use `iproute2` for this rules so config will be the same for local and forwarded packets.